# Why is this jpg 0 bytes and websites often can't upload it?

Tags: jpeg, file-format, forensics

I have a certain cellphone with a Gallery app that makes so-called 0 byte files. In fact the file you're looking at is one of them. So maybe somebody could tell me what's the matter with the format?
[image: File listing]

What happens is, let's say I take a screenshot. And then I decided to edit it a little. Well that creates the so-called 0 byte file. But it's not really zero bytes. It depends on which application you look at it with. Smarter applications will show its real size.

And smarter websites will allow me to upload it. But then the other websites just fail because they think it's invalid.

Sure, if I'm desperate to upload it to website A, I could always upload it first to website B  and then download it again and then upload it to website A and it will work fine. (Because website B will regurgitate it, stripping some stuff out etc. and making it into a new file.) In fact above you see a second version that Facebook fixed up for me.

But after years of doing this, it just strikes me that I ought to ask and just find out what's wrong with the format. Is there some metadata byte missing here or some kind of skipped binary digit there or what? Thank you. Oh by the way it's a Asus Zenfone 3! With genuine stock applications from 5 years ago when they got frozen in stone (no more updates.)

And no, all the online tools that I found  just  find other aspects. ... if your jpg is not pretty enough etc. they're not concerned about the raw file format.

Anyway, today's question is simply an intellectual curiosity for me. I'm not in some kind of desperate state of trying to make the Asus Corporation do something better or whatever. I mean I already own a brand new spanking Samsung in fact.

Anyway I was going to post the subject of those tiny little thumbnails, but then I realized well that picture above you see is in fact an also a so-called zero byte file so you might as well just analyze that for me. Thank you.

And by zero byte I don't mean like somebody's panicking because the files are zero byte on their computer. I'm just saying that even though the thumbnail shows up but next to it is  zero bytes. But that's a software problem ... but I'm trying to find out what's the problem with the format that is provoking it. Thank you.

Oh and by the way if stack exchange modifies the file that I uploaded, then all bets are off.

Comment: Can you download again the file you posted and check it's identical to the one you  uploaded? Of check that the MD5 hash is `4fa568820866a9bb97d49bfed3960244`? Can't see anything significantly different between your file and a screenshot from my phone so far. Otherwise put the file in a  ZIP and upload the ZIP.

Comment: Yes I was just thinking about that. Well turns out it's 1,000 bytes different so.. let me think of another idea to transmit it into your guy's hands unscrewed up. Maybe I'll compressing into a Gz.. one moment please

Comment: https://filebin.net/f782zymqtg3ou3t7 is the location where I put the pristine file that will be there for six whole days. Thank you

Comment: I am not sure that this is a photography question and not a tech support question about the smartphone or app that you are using.

Comment: This question is about a hardware/software issue that is only tangentially related to photography.

Answer (score 2):

There was a bug with android 8 where third party apps writing to the SD card could create 0 byte files. So whatever app you are using to edit the image has a write issue.

The fix was to use internal storage and then use the native file manager to move them to the SD. Or use the native file manager to move the files into internal storage and back to the card again.

Comment: All I know is this kind of file can't be up uploaded to github. It can be uploaded to Facebook and stack. It says zero bytes in the gallery listing but displays fine anyway. But the file manager listing shows it as 50 kb.

Comment: And by the way that cell phone doesn't have a physical SD card. Anyway your solution sounds great, except how does it explain why such files can't be uploaded to github but can be to Facebook and stack? Thank you.

Comment: I just tried again with GitHub (attaching to an issue). It says the file is too large. No matter if I choose it from the gallery, or from the file manager.

Comment: OK, now on desktop I uploaded the suspect file to GitHub, and it worked. So that means the cellphone is telling the website this file is zero bytes, etc.